# element.id not recognized as variable name

Tags: jquery, variables

Struggling with this one. I have a few images shown as thumbnails. When a user clicks on one of those thumbnails, I want the image to appear in big in another frame (svg format).

In my html I have:

```
<div class="inner-fyt bottom-left">

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 255 378" style="enable-background:new 0 0 255 378;" xml:space="preserve">

        <path id="userselectedillustration" class="st0" d="M0,256.6c5,0.6,9.8,1.8,14.6,3.4c3.6,1.3,9.4,4.2,14.6,7.1c5,2.8,9.1,5.1,15.3,6.8c2.3,0.6,4.4,0.8,6.8,1.3 c7.2,1.5,11.4,3.2,11.8,2.4c0.4-0.8-3.6-3.7-7.1-6.1c-6-4.1-12.5-8.3-17.3-11.9c-4-3.1-12-12.8-18.4-22.7 c-4.7-7.2-9.1-16.1-13.1-26.5c-1.6-4.1-3.5-9.9-3.1-17.3c0.4-7.6,2.6-12.5,5-15.9c2-2.8,4.5-5.1,7.5-6.9c4.6-2.7,9-3,10.5-2.7" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

and then:

```
<div class="container customization_divider illustrations_thumbnails_container">

<label for="illustration">Pick an illustration</label><br />
<img id="ticket" src="thumbnails\ticket_thumbnail.png" onclick=illustrationselection(this) class="img-thumbnail illustration_thumbnail" alt="ticket">
<img id="baby_feet" src="thumbnails\baby_feet_thumbnail.png" onclick=illustrationselection(this) class="img-thumbnail illustration_thumbnail" alt="baby_feet">

</div>
```

Then in Javascript file:

```
var ticket = "M14.1,152.9c3.2-0.9,6-2.8,7.8-5.4c1.5-2.2,2.2-4.4,2.2-5.3c0-1.1-0.2-1.7,0.2-2.6c1-2.1,4.4-2.3,6.9-2.6 c1.7-0.2,5.5-1.6,8.7-2.7c2.6-0.9,4.8-2,7.4-3.1c4.6-1.9,9-3.2,14.1-4.6c15.1-4.1,30.4-8.6,44.3-11.8c6.4-1.5,12.7-2.8,19.1-4.1 c13.8-2.7,27-4.6,40.9-7.2c7.4-1.4,16.1-2.3,18.4"

var baby_feet ="M0,256.6c5,0.6,9.8,1.8,14.6,3.4c3.6,1.3,9.4,4.2,14.6,7.1c5,2.8,9.1,5.1,15.3,6.8c2.3,0.6,4.4,0.8,6.8,1.3 c7.2,1.5,11.4,3.2,11.8,2.4c0.4-0.8-3.6-3.7-7.1-6.1c-6-4.1-12.5-8.3-17.3-11.9c-4-3.1-12-12.8-18.4-22.7 c-4.7-7.2-9.1-16.1-13.1-26.5c-1.6-4.1-3.5-9.9-3.1-17.3c0.4-7.6,2.6-12.5"

function illustrationselection(el){
//retrieve the clickedthumbnail ID
  var clickedillustration=el.id;
//use the id as variable to set the svg path (ie if ticket is clicked, then use var ticket)

$("#userselectedillustration").attr("d", clickedillustration);}
```

When I console.log(clickedillustration) it renders "ticket" or "baby_feet" (without the quotes) so that seems to "work" but when I console.log($("#userselectedillustration").attr("d")) then the return is empty.

Essentially the question is how can i pass my el.id to be recognized as a variable to use in setting the "d" attribute ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: What does ticket and baby_feet have to do with the rest of the incomplete code you posted? How do you call illustrationselection

Comment: Hi @mplungjan, thanks for the comment, sorry I am new here. I've added the html components where I call the ilustrationselection function. Wasn't sure about pasting my full code or just the areas to focus on.

Comment: Note: Get into the practice of using [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) so it is easier to read your variable names.

Answer (score 0):

The id does not magically map to your variable name. You are literally just putting the string as the attribute.

You need to reference the variable. Easiest way is an object.

```
const settings = {
  ticket : "M14.1,152......",
  baby_feet : "M0,256......",
};
```

And then you can reference the object with your id

```
$("#userselectedillustration").attr("d", settings[clickedillustration]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @epascarello ! This works perfectly (I needed to pay attention to the commas in the Object). And noted about the camelCase !